# Android - onClick function doesn't work in fragments

Tags: android, kotlin

i have a fragment in my quiz app and it has 4 buttons with onClick function " checkAnswer" like below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".View.QuizFragment"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:ignore="OnClick" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/count_label"
        android:textSize="22sp"/>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/questionLabel"
        android:text="@string/question_label"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/answerBtn1"
        android:text="@string/btn_answer"
        android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:onClick="checkAnswer"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/answerBtn2"
        android:text="@string/btn_answer"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:onClick="checkAnswer"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/answerBtn3"
        android:text="@string/btn_answer"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:onClick="checkAnswer"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/answerBtn4"
        android:text="@string/btn_answer"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        style="?attr/materialButtonOutlinedStyle"
        android:onClick="checkAnswer"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

In activity it is okay to define the onClick func like fun checkAnswer(view : View){}

But when i want to try it in a fragment, it doesn't work. I get an error:

*java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method checkAnswer(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton with id 'answerBtn3'*

```
fun checkAnswer(view : View) {
        // get pushed button 
        val answerBtn: Button = view.findViewById(view.id)
        val btnText = answerBtn.text.toString()
....
}
```

Is there a way to fix this or do i have to do it with setOnClickListener?

Comment: "Is there a way to fix this" -- there are solutions involving data binding. I recommend using `setOnClickListener()`.

Comment: You should basically always use `setOnClickListener()` rather than `android:onClick` anyways. That way, you can tell just from looking at your Kotlin file what code is called for which click action.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, i will use `setOnClickListener()`